# How to add custom drop-down in admin product image section

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, product-attribute, product-images

I am trying to add a custom drop-down in Product edit page.
I want to add this drop-down in each image of the product.
Please see the following screenshot how I want to show the drop-down.

[image]

Can someone help and guide me how to achieve this functionality?
I found a phtml file where I can add a drop-down field but I need a help to store this value to each image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout` observer event for that and override **gallery.phtml** file.

Follow the below steps to add custom drop-down in product edit form :

1) Create **events.xml** file on this below path for add events `catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout` :

> /app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout">
        <observer name="change_template" disabled="true"/>
        <observer name="custom_change_template" instance="RH\Helloworld\Observer\ChangeTemplateObserver" />
    </event> 
</config>
```

2) Create **ChangeTemplateObserver.php** file for prepare layout of product gallery :

> /app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/Observer

```
<?php

namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeTemplateObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $observer->getBlock()->setTemplate('CompanyName_ModuleName::helper/gallery.phtml');
    }
}
```

3) Create **gallery.phtml** on the below path for make layout of product gallery :

> /app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/templates/helper

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\Gallery\Content */
$elementName = $block->getElement()->getName() . '[images]';
$formName = $block->getFormName();
?>
<div id="<?= $block->getHtmlId() ?>"
     class="gallery"
     data-mage-init='{"productGallery":{"template":"#<?= $block->getHtmlId() ?>-template"}}'
     data-parent-component="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getData('config/parentComponent')) ?>"
     data-images="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getImagesJson()) ?>"
     data-types="<?= $block->escapeHtml(
         $this->helper('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($block->getImageTypes())
     ) ?>"
    >
    <?php if (!$block->getElement()->getReadonly()) {?>
        <div class="image image-placeholder">
            <?= $block->getUploaderHtml() ?>
            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                <p class="image-placeholder-text">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Browse to find or drag image here') ?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php foreach ($block->getImageTypes() as $typeData) {
    ?>
        <input name="<?= $block->escapeHtml($typeData['name']) ?>"
               data-form-part="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $formName ?>"
               class="image-<?= $block->escapeHtml($typeData['code']) ?>"
               type="hidden"
               value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($typeData['value']) ?>"/>
    <?php

} ?>

    <script id="<?= $block->getHtmlId() ?>-template" type="text/x-magento-template">
        <div class="image item<% if (data.disabled == 1) { %> hidden-for-front<% } %>"
             data-role="image">
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][position]"
                   value="<%- data.position %>"
                   data-form-part="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $formName ?>"
                   class="position"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][file]"
                   data-form-part="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $formName ?>"
                   value="<%- data.file %>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][value_id]"
                   data-form-part="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $formName ?>"
                   value="<%- data.value_id %>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][label]"
                   data-form-part="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $formName ?>"
                   value="<%- data.label %>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][disabled]"
                   data-form-part="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $formName ?>"
                   value="<%- data.disabled %>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][displayimage]"
                   data-form-part="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $formName ?>"
                   value="<%- data.displayimage %>"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][media_type]"
                   data-form-part="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $formName ?>"
                   value="image"/>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][removed]"
                   data-form-part="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $formName ?>"
                   value=""
                   class="is-removed"/>

            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                <img class="product-image"
                     data-role="image-element"
                     src="<%- data.url %>"
                     alt="<%- data.label %>"/>

                <div class="actions">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="action-remove"
                            data-role="delete-button"
                            title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Delete image') ?>">
                    <span>
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Delete image') ?>
                    </span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="draggable-handle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="image-fade"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Hidden') ?></span></div>
            </div>


            <div class="item-description">
                <div class="item-title" data-role="img-title"><%- data.label %></div>
                <div class="item-size">
                  <span data-role="image-dimens"></span>, <span data-role="image-size"><%- data.sizeLabel %></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <ul class="item-roles" data-role="roles-labels">
                <?php
                foreach ($block->getImageTypes() as $typeData) {
                    ?>
                    <li data-role-code="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml(
                        $typeData['code']
                    ) ?>" class="item-role item-role-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml(
                        $typeData['code']
                    ) ?>">
                        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->escapeHtml($typeData['label']) ?>
                    </li>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </script>

    <script data-role="img-dialog-container-tmpl" type="text/x-magento-template">
      <div class="image-panel" data-role="dialog">
      </div>
    </script>

    <script data-role="img-dialog-tmpl" type="text/x-magento-template">
            <div class="image-panel-preview">
                <img src="<%- data.url %>" alt="<%- data.label %>" />
            </div>
            <div class="image-panel-controls">
                <strong class="image-name"><%- data.label %></strong>

                <fieldset class="admin__fieldset fieldset-image-panel">
                    <div class="admin__field field-image-description">
                        <label class="admin__field-label" for="image-description">
                            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Alt Text') ?></span>
                        </label>

                        <div class="admin__field-control">
                            <textarea data-role="image-description"
                                      rows="3"
                                      class="admin__control-textarea"
                                      name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                                      echo $elementName
                                      ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][label]"><%- data.label %></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="admin__field field-image-role">
                        <label class="admin__field-label">
                            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Role') ?></span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="admin__field-control">
                            <ul class="multiselect-alt">
                                <?php
                                foreach ($block->getMediaAttributes() as $attribute) :
                                    ?>
                                    <li class="item">
                                        <label>
                                            <input class="image-type"
                                                   data-role="type-selector"
                                                   data-form-part="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $formName ?>"
                                                   type="checkbox"
                                                   value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml(
                                                       $attribute->getAttributeCode()
                                                   ) ?>"
                                                />
                                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->escapeHtml(
                                                $attribute->getFrontendLabel()
                                            ) ?>
                                        </label>
                                    </li>
                                <?php
                                endforeach;
                                ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="admin__field field-display-image">
                        <div class="admin__field-control">
                            <div class="admin__field admin__field-option">
                                <label for="display-image-from-product-page-<%- data.file_id %>" class="admin__field-label">
                                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Custom Image Type') ?>
                                </label>
                                <select class="admin__control-select" data-bind="attr: {name: inputName,id: uid,disabled: disabled,'aria-describedby': noticeId},
                                        hasFocus: focused,
                                        optgroup: options,
                                        value: value,
                                        optionsCaption: caption,
                                        optionsValue: 'value',
                                        optionsText: 'label'" name="custom-dropdown-name" id="custom-dropdown-id">
                                        <option data-title="type1" value="1">Type1</option>
                                        <option data-title="type1" value="2">Type2</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="admin__field admin__field-inline field-image-size" data-role="size">
                        <label class="admin__field-label">
                            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Image Size') ?></span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="admin__field-value" data-message="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('{size}') ?>"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="admin__field admin__field-inline field-image-resolution" data-role="resolution">
                        <label class="admin__field-label">
                            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Image Resolution') ?></span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="admin__field-value" data-message="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('{width}^{height} px') ?>"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="admin__field field-image-hide">
                        <div class="admin__field-control">
                            <div class="admin__field admin__field-option">
                                <input type="checkbox"
                                       id="hide-from-product-page"
                                       data-role="visibility-trigger"
                                       data-form-part="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $formName ?>"
                                       value="1"
                                       class="admin__control-checkbox"
                                       name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $elementName ?>[<%- data.file_id %>][disabled]"
                                <% if (data.disabled == 1) { %>checked="checked"<% } %> />

                                <label for="hide-from-product-page" class="admin__field-label">
                                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Hide from Product Page') ?>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
    </script>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('new-video') ?>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery('body').trigger('contentUpdated');
</script>
```

Output :

[image]

For more reference : [click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/230077/51810)

**Hope, It will helpful for you.**

Comment: Okay. Happy to help !! Happy coding :) You can accept answer if it's working for you or if you face issue then, let me know.

Comment: Hi. How did you save the selected dropdown value in the database?